# Safari and Firefox input elements do not get focus on click

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I am not quite sure how to ask this question.

I wrote the website http://math.qb.is, first I did this in jQuery and Handlebars, then I rewrote it in AngularJS, but the end result is the same. Only the first question will get focus, and trying to click on any element will just refocus the first item. You can use the TAB key to move around, but that is not a solution. This works as expected in Chrome. I have not been able yet to test this on IE, but both latest Safari and FireFox fail on this.

I know it is frowned upon to send people off the site, but I just can't describe this problem except for dynamically generated input fields can't get focus, or something like that, which really isn't exactly the problem.

The site is just Javascript, no backend except to serve the index file.

All files are not minimized. All help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't put multiple inputs inside a single label**. By default, any click on label will focus the  first input. Rather try to wrap the inputs with different labels. This will solve your issue. It has nothing to do with angular/handlebar, it's just a html/css issue. Try different html element except label, if you want to wrap.

Here is a simple example:

```
<label>Click me
    <input type="text" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" />
</label>
<br/>
<br/>
<label>Click me
    <input type="text" />
</label>
<label>Click me
    <input type="text" />
</label>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/KN9xx/322/

Comment: Oh my is my face red now, one un closed label. Thank you so much